# use current date on date add function codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

this is the query of my model

```
public function input_leave($effectivity){

    $input = array( 'ID_NUM' => $this->input->post('ID_NUM'),
                    'SOLO_P' => $this->input->post('SOLO_P'),
                    'DATE_ENTITLED' => date("Y-m-d"),
                    'EFFECTIVITY'   => DATE_ADD(now("Y-m-d") ,INTERVAL .$effectivity. MONTH)
                    );
    $insert = $this->db->insert('tbl_leave',$input);
    return $insert;
}
```

i want is to do is `DATE_ADD(**the current date** ,INTERVAL .$effectivity. MONTH)`

but when i use now() it does not work, i still dont fully understand DATE_ADD function so can someone please explain what the error is and what the solution is. thanks.

Comment: `now()` does not take a datetime format string

Answer (score 5):

You're confusing MySQL's `NOW()` function with PHP's `date()` function. MySQL's `NOW()` does not take any parameters:

```
$input = array( 'ID_NUM' => $this->input->post('ID_NUM'),
                    'SOLO_P' => $this->input->post('SOLO_P'),
                    'DATE_ENTITLED' => date("Y-m-d"),
                    'EFFECTIVITY'   => DATE_ADD(NOW() ,INTERVAL .$effectivity. MONTH)
                    );
    $insert = $this->db->insert('tbl_leave',$input);
    return $insert;
```

Comment: so what should i do?

Comment: You may want to echo that query out and verify it is what you are expecting. Then run it from the command line or a tool like phpmyadmin to see how it runs.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do this with php like this

```
$input = array( 'ID_NUM' => $this->input->post('ID_NUM'),
                'SOLO_P' => $this->input->post('SOLO_P'),
                'DATE_ENTITLED' => date("Y-m-d"),
                'EFFECTIVITY'   => date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+".$effectivity." months"))
                );
$insert = $this->db->insert('tbl_leave',$input);
return $insert;
```